# Postfix: reject mail, but still deliver or archive in a folder for spam analysis

Tags: email, postfix, spam, spamassassin

I'm using Postfix and Spamassassin, and Postfix is rejecting incoming mail that fall into spam rules. Mail are then forwarded to different relays based on many factors.

Is there a way to archive rejected mails somewhere for spam analysis/training, or (would be better) to make Postfix still deliver them in background with a specific header added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with Postfix. You'll need to run a different process between the content checker (in this case SpamAssassin) and the MTA. For example `amavisd`.

Comment: amavisd is actually running and configured together with postfix and spamassassin. Any hint on how to do it? I couldn't find a good way for it.

Comment: @St0rM That would be a different question to ask.